# How do you add functions to a class and ensure intellisense will recognise those functions?

Tags: python, python-3.x, decorator, intellisense

Intellisense does not recognise someFunc() in the code below.

```
def someFunc(self):
    print("YAY")


def mydec(func):
    @functools.wraps(func)
    def dec_inner(*args,**kwargs):
        setattr(func,"someFunc", someFunc)
        re = func(*args,**kwargs)
        return re
    
    return dec_inner

@mydec
class MyClass:
    ...


myInstance = MyClass()
myInstance.someFunc() # Intellisense does not recognise someFunc()
```

I am sure it is possible because @dataclass gets the class object and modifies it then returns it and Intellisense recognises the added functions.

I would like Intellisense to work. I have tried using MethodType amongst other things. I have also been trying to look through the dataclass library but it is a lot.

Comment: Seems like since it only adds `someFunc` to `mydec` at runtime, there'd be no way for a static tool like intellisense to have any idea that the two are supposed to be related. I would think that you would have to add a wrapper class or stub out the method or something, so that static analysis can work.

Comment: Surely `mydec` should return a class, not a function, no?

Comment: A mix-in class might make more sense than a decorator here.

Answer (score 1):

Define a protocol that asserts the existence of `someFunc`.

```
from typing import Protocol

class HasSomeFunc(Protocol):
    def someFunc(self):
        ...
```

Then type-hint `mydec` (which needs to be defined significantly differently) to assert it returns something of type `HasSomeFunc`:

```
def mydec(cls) -> HasSomeFunc:
    setattr(cls, "someFunc", someFunc)
    return cls
```